# MVC Razor - form values empty when submitted from outside the form

Tags: html, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.beginform

I building a MVC (Razor) project, and I have a view (ViewA) with a partial view (ViewB) inside. The partial view has a form (@BeginForm)

Here is the form:

```
@model MT_Contacts.Models.ContactInfo
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 35%;" colspan="2">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Name))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.Name))
                <br />
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Address1))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.Address1))
                <br />
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Address2))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.Address2))
                <br />
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Address3))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.Address3))
                <br />
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.ZipAndCity))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.ZipAndCity))
                <br />
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Country))
            {
                @(Html.Raw(Model.Country))
                <br />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.Phone))
    {
        <tr><td style="width: 35%;">Telefon</td><td>: @Html.Raw(Model.Phone) </td></tr>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInfoChanges", "ContactInfoBox", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditContactInfoForm" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address2)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ZipAndCity)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Country)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Phone)
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address3</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address3, new { placeholder = "test placeholder", style = "width:300px" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

As a test, I am just trying to edit the Address3 property.
When using the submit input inside the form, everything works fine. But I need it to be outside the form, in the main view.

In my main view (ViewA) I have tried this:

```
<input type="submit" value="abc" form="EditContactInfoForm" />
```

But that appears to do nothing.

I have also tried this (in ViewA):

```
<td class="boxIcons" id="ContactInfoHeaderAcceptButton" onclick="saveInfoChanges();">
    Save
</td>
```

Executing this in ViewA:

```
function saveInfoChanges() {
    $("#EditContactInfoForm").submit();
};
```

This gets me to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveInfoChanges(ContactInfo editedContactInfoResult)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Here, the parameter (editedContactInfoResult) is not null, but is a ContactInfo object with all porperties as null.

I can't seem to find any solution for this. I hope that you can help!

**EDIT:**

This is the ContactInfo object:

```
namespace Contacts.Models
{
    public class ContactInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string ZipAndCity { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried moving the submit buttons from ViewA to the partial view (ViewB). In there, the `<input type="submit" value="abc" form="EditContactInfoForm"/>` still does nothing. But the saveInfoChanges() works perfectly.

Is there no way that I can move the submit button to ViewA?

**EDIT 3:**

Main view (ViewA):

```
@using MT_Contacts.Models
@model ContactInfo

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/InfoBoxStyle.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Basic/Tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Basic/ContactInfoBox.js"></script>

<div ID="InfoBox">
    <table class="infobox">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Kontaktinfo
                </th>
                <th id="tester1" style="text-align: right">
                    <table id="HoverButtonTable" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle">
                        <tr style="text-align: right">
                            <td style="width: 100%"></td>

                            <td class="boxIcons" id="ContactInfoHeaderEditButton" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; font-size: 10px" onclick="ContactInfoBox.toggleEditMode('1')">
                                L
                            </td>

                            <td class="boxIcons" id="ContactInfoHeaderAcceptButton" style="display: none; vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; font-size: 10px" onclick="saveInfoChanges();">
                                &#xe2a0;
                            </td>
                            <td id="ContactInfoHeaderSpace" style="display: none"> &#160 </td>
                            <td class="boxIcons" id="ContactInfoHeaderCanselButton" style="display: none; vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; font-size: 10px" onclick="ContactInfoBox.toggleEditMode('0');">
                                &#xe262;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" id="contactInfoList">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("InfoBoxes/ContactInfoBox/_ContactInfoList", Model);}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The `form` should work fine so long as the browser supports it. If your properties are all the default values in the POST method, it suggests you might have fields rather that properties (no getter/setter)

Comment: When I have my submit inside the form itself, it does work. It is only when the submit is outside the form that I run into problems. I have added the ContactInfo class.

Comment: The model is fine. And your `$("#EditContactInfoForm").submit();` will also work fine. If its not, there is something else causing the issue that you have not shown us

Comment: The problem seems to be that the submit button is in the parrent view. (see edit2)

Comment: Do you happen to be loading that partial after the initial page load (via ajax)?

Comment: Added ViewA in edit 3. The `$("#EditContactInfoForm").submit();` have been in both views with the same result. I Hope that answers your question?

Comment: Are you using some kind of JavaScript to fill the hidden fields from the non-hidden fields?  My guess is that this script is hooking the button to function, and thus only works when it's in the form field, and when the button is actually clicked.

Comment: Also, technically, you have illegal code here.  The HTML spec does not allow elements such as hidden fields to be inside a table, but outside of a cell.  This could also be a contributing factor.  I would suggest placing the form outside of the table, as well as the hidden elements (but within the form)

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch
I removed the table around the form, and it now works. Thanks! If you want, you can add it as a answer, and I will mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you have illegal code here. The HTML spec does not allow elements such as hidden fields to be inside a table, but outside of a cell. This could also be a contributing factor. I would suggest placing the form outside of the table, as well as the hidden elements (but within the form)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...)
{
    <table> 
      ...
    </table>
    @Html.HiddenFor(...)
}
```